# Generate visualforce page from standard page layout

Tags: visualforce, lightning, new

My app is in lightning experience. I want to add custom address search javascript component to my custom object record creation form.

First i tried to get the address search work in lightning component, but i had to import the external javascript component as static resource, because you can not use `<scrtipt>` tags in lightning component. I couldn't get it to work.

Then i tried to use visualforce page for that. I got the address searching functionality working. I override "new" button with VF page. Now i am looking for a way to replicate the exact form of my custom object record creation form and my idea is to just add the search form there.

Is there a way to replicate the look&feel and standard page fields out of the box or i have to do it all manually, that is my question.

[image: This is what my address search looks like.]
[image: Example of my standard page form]

These address search fields are not available on a custom object thats why i need to implement custom address search. Showing this form for an example.

Comment: Have you looked at the [`<apex:detail>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_detail.htm) component? For what purpose are you making a Visualforce page that looks exactly like the standard layout?

Comment: More Importantly, if it's *exact*.... why do you need VF? Can you elaborate on your need?

Comment: @SebastianKessel I need to add a custom address search functionality from external source, and i can't add it any other way to replicate the standard page and put it in the form. At least i could not figure out any other way.

Comment: @DavidReed I tried to use <apex: detail> component, but it did not work.

Comment: @RSICK This information that's coming out in comments should be in your question. Share with us what you're aiming at and what you've tried or we just end up in a guessing game. If apex:detail didn't work for you, say why.

Comment: @DavidReed thank you for answering. I can't use <apex:detail> because, it is for created record and it need subject="" as attribute, but when I create new record I do not have ID yet, so thats not working. I will update my question for better understunding.